# Easiest way to have closed comments on a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, private

My site has several different kinds of post types. One of these is Discussions.

The site is completely open and public, but my client has asked that I provide a space where only certain members can have discussions/post comments.  Basically, I want only members/authors/editors/whoevers of my site to see/post new Discussions.

I've explored using bbpress and other forum options, but they're all too complicated.

Is it even possible in WordPress to have only registered users see/post to a Discussions post type?

Thanks

Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Template Tags for the rescue

1. Only logged in users:

   ```
   is_user_logged_in()
   ```
2. Only logged in users that have a certain capability assigned to their role

   ```
   current_user_can($capability)
   ```
3. Only logged in users that have a specific role assigned

   ```
   current_user_has_role($role)
   ```
4. Only logged in users that have a specific capability assigned (to their role) on a specific blog

   ```
   current_user_can_for_blog($blog_id, $capability)
   ```

Comment: Ack. Right. Exactly right. Its always the template tags. Thanks for this!